# Post is marked as spam and hidden

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, spam, not-an-answer, specific-answer

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531602/bulk-update-in-entity-framework-core/62726789) was deleted by a moderator.

The answer was once upvoted, is specific to the question and even contains a link to a fiddle that demonstrates a working solution. Even more than that, the fiddle is eventually the same example that supports the [#2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43543334/263116), just using a different technology for the solution.

I assumed that the answer was deleted by mistake and gave it again. But it was marked as spam as well.

So I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you linking to your own work or product elsewhere on the internet and (a) not disclosing your affiliation with that work and (b) not summarizing the solution in the text of your answer *on this site*, so people OP can solve his problem without visiting your link?

Comment: Not only that answer was deleted but your [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726789/578411), an exact re-post for the deleted answer, was deleted as well by a different mod. A user also left a comment to inform you that your earlier answer was deleted.

Comment: Relevant: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Comment: And also relevant, from the help center: [How not to be spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Disclosure is just one component of what would make a post not spam. I actually _missed_ that the link was to a fiddle rather than to your own site because you included a disclaimer, and otherwise nothing but a link. It reads like this: *Hi, I'm the maintainer of project XYZ, which does what you want, go look here:*. I am none the wiser as to how to solve the problem or why I should use your project to do so. Try to _answer the problem_ rather than (appear to) promote your project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Any answer that references a project with my involvement may be looked as a promotion. Clearly I'm a domain expert and can give the best answer related to the work I do. So giving an expert answer is a bad thing to do if I'm affiliated with the project? And again, what about the #2 answer which does more or less the same? Indeed I'm interested that more folks would use the project, but because it's great! (my project is free, and the #2 is not)

Comment: @KonstantinTriger no one said anything about you answering with expertise being a bad thing. That’s completely misreading what I tried to say. I’m saying the way you answered is bad, not the fact that you answer.

Comment: What other differences do you think there might be between your answer and the one with the second-highest vote count there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852314/2579738) wasn't deleted as spam. It was just deleted. Probably because it consists of nothing more than a link to a off-site resource. A fiddle link may only be used as supplementary material for an answer but not as the main part of it.

Your second answer has been spam-deleted. Probably for reposting the exact same content again.

Comment: It was not spam-deleted. Both were deleted by moderators, but the second one received one spam flag that wasn't dismissed when the moderator deleted the post.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do in this case? Can I restore the answer (and add more details)?